# Customize android app permissions description content

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there a way to describe about each permission in our own words in an android app ? For ex. if i'm requesting a "access-GPS" permission, can i put my own words in the description area inside the permissions dialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible - would be nice sometimes to add something ( e.g. why you want this particular permission ) but replacing the description is a security problem

Comment: Has this changed in previous years?