# Android permissions description labels

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a question regarding labels that show up during app installation on android. As you can see on the screenshot below, some of the descriptions of the permissions start with lower case letter, but some of them start with capital case letter. Is there a way fro unify this? If so, how can I do that?

The only info about this I found on forum was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364539/customize-android-app-permissions-description-content), but it seems little outdated.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no changes which will give us control over the description. This information is populated by OS and unavailable for edit from the application.